# Style Headers: Remove margins from W3.CSS

Tags: html, css, asp.net, header

```css
.main_header 
{ 
  background: tomato;
  height: 250px;
  width:100%;
  margin:0 !important;
  padding:0 !important;
  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

 <div style="padding:0 !important; margin:0 !important;" class="w3-container w3-red">
        <p>test</p>    
  </div>
  
   <div class ="main_header">
   <p> test_2</p>
   </div>
```

While attempting to add in the middle of a `page.aspx`, a `header` section with a defined `background-color`, I've used 2 approaches:

**1.:**

*a - add in the Master page:*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
```

*b- Use in the targeted `page.aspx`:*

```
<div style="padding:0 !important; margin:0 !important;" class="w3-container w3-red">
            <p>test</p>
        </div>
```

**2.:**

*c - define in the Master page:*

```
<style type="text/css">

....

.main_header 
{ 
  background: tomato;
  height: 250px;
  width:100%;
  margin:0 !important;
  padding:0 !important; 
}
</style>
```

*d- Then use in the targeted `page.aspx`:*

`<div class ="main_header"></div>`

==> Both approaches (1 & 2) yield the same outcome: the bar/header sections appear in center of the page. However I was expecting both `left/right-margins` to be removed so as to make the bar/header sections displayed all across the web page like a `fixed Navbar`.

**NB**: Note that applying in the `style sheet` did not help:

```
html, body{
  margin:0 !important;
  padding:0 !important;
}
```

Thus, any explanation/idea would highly be appreciated.

Comment: @Paulie_D: snippet added, cheers. Hoping it would be helpful enough, as you cannot see the empty margins after running it.

Comment: If you can't reproduce the issue we really can't diagnose it.

Comment: @Paulie_D: thanks your your help, in regards to the snippet. Sounds like several ```stylesheets``` referred in the ```Master.page``` are conflicting yielding this bizzare outcome. As a way around I am isolating some forms from other with Master file.